# Optimize nested for loops for calculation on a matrix in r

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

I created a script in R to calculate nucleotide diversity in a bunch of DNA sequence files (fasta format). I can do it using nested for loops (see code below). However, it’s computationally very inefficient. I’ve tried ifelse and sapply functions, but can figure out how to make it work. May anybody help me optimize this code?

```
# This code works but it’s very inefficient:
library(pegas)
setwd(dir="d:/my_directory")
file.names<-dir(pattern=".fasta")

# Create a nucleotide diversity matrix:
exple<-matrix(nrow=10,ncol=10)
rownames(exple)<-paste("sample",c(1:10),sep="_")
colnames(exple)<-paste("species",c(1:10),sep="_")

# Create a function to read DNA sequences and calculate nucleotide diversity:
pi=function(x,y){
  my_seq<-read.dna(paste(x,y,"fasta",sep="."),format="fasta",as.matrix=FALSE)
  nuc_div<-nuc.div(my_seq)
  }

# Iterate over rows and columns
for(m in 1:nrow(exple)){
  for(o in 1:ncol(exple)){
    if(paste(colnames(exple)[o],rownames(exple)[m],"fasta",sep=".") %in% dir()){
      divp <- pi(colnames(exple)[o],rownames(exple)[m])
      exple[m,o]<-divp
    } 
  }
}
```

My try (one of many) to make it efficient:

```
exple2<-melt(exple,varnames=c("sample","species"))
exple2$exist<-ifelse(paste(exple2$species,exple2$sample,"fasta",sep=".") %in% dir(),1,0)
exple2$value<-ifelse(exple2$exist==1,
                  sapply(exple2$sample, function(x){
                    pi(exple2$species,exple2$sample)
}),"NA")

# I get this error
Error in file(con, "rb") : invalid 'description' argument

# Traceback
10. file(con, "rb")
9.  readBin(file, "raw", sz)
8.  read.FASTA(file)
7.  read.dna(paste(x, y, "fasta", sep = "."), format = "fasta", as.matrix = FALSE)
6.  pi(exple2$otu_id, exple2$sample_id)
5.  FUN(X[[i]], ...)
4.  lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
3.  sapply(exple2$sample_id, function(x) { pi(exple2$otu_id, exple2$sample_id) })
2.  sapply(exple2$sample_id, function(x) { pi(exple2$otu_id, exple2$sample_id) })
1.  ifelse(exple2$exist == 1, sapply(exple2$sample_id, function(x) { pi(exple2$otu_id, exple2$sample_id) }), "NA")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error raises due to passing a vector of multiple elements into the [`read.dna`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ape/versions/5.3/topics/read.dna) file argument which expects a length of one. Since you essentially are running all combinations between two character vectors, consider `mapply` for elementwise loop down an `expand.grid` data frame to build needed matrix of results. Plus, use `tryCatch` for missing files:

```
pi <- function(x, y) {
  tryCatch({
     my_seq <- read.dna(paste(x, y, "fasta", sep="."), 
                        format="fasta", as.matrix=FALSE)
     return(nuc.div(my_seq))
    }, error = function (e) return(NULL)
  )
}

# DATA FRAME OF ALL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS (nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
params_df <- expand.grid(sample = paste("sample", c(1:10), sep="_"),
                         species = paste("species", c(1:10), sep="_"))

# CAST NUMERIC VECTOR INTO MATRIX OF DEFINED DIMS
exple <- matrix(mapply(pi, params_df$species, params_df$sample),
                nrow = 10, ncol = 10,
                dimnames = list(paste("sample", c(1:10), sep="_"),
                                paste("species", c(1:10), sep="_"))
               )
```

With the said, since you are reading files iteratively in an I/O process, so cannot be vectorized, this solution may not be much faster but you avoid multiple nested `for` looping into one hidden *apply* family loop.

Comment: Great! Many thanks, it works and in much shorter time.

Just a minor correction: mapply(pi, params_df$species, params_df$sample)

Comment: Just for information: the code with nested for loops took 4043 seconds, the optimized one proposed here took 69 seconds. It is indeed much faster!

Comment: Great to hear! Very interesting! Thank you for that feedback.